# SpecFlow Allure report

Tags: c#, specflow, allure, nunit-3.0

I download this example where is configured Allure using Specflow and Nunit 3:
https://github.com/jakismichal/simplespecflowproject

But when I tried to execute one of the features I get this error: 
Message: OneTimeSetUp: TechTalk.SpecFlow.SpecFlowException : Unable to load plugin: Allure. Please check http://go.specflow.org/doc-plugins for details.
  ----> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'Allure.SpecFlowPlugin' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I also see the same error in one of my personal projects with same error. I only installed Specflow.Allure package.

Am I missing something ? or it is a bug of SpecFlow.Allure ?

Answer (score 1):

SpecFlow wants to load the SpecFlow.Allure runtime plugin.
Make sure it is in your bin\Debug folder.

Please also consider, that the plugin has to work with the SpecFlow version. 
We had in every new version a breaking change in the plugin interface. So your version of SpecFlow.Allure has to work with your SpecFlow version.
Not everytime the NuGet packages have set the dependencies right. Be aware of this.

Comment: Allure.SpecFlowPlugin assembly is not in bin\Debug folder maybe as you mentioned that it is because the version but I did'n't change the version of the example I used and installed the packages according to packages.config file.  ... But now I don't know what I need to do

Comment: You have SpecFlow.Allure in your package.config, but it is not referenced in your project. Try reinstalling the package and look at the output of the package manager console.

Comment: I also reinstall the Specflow.Allure but the library is not copied to bin if I go to packages folder and copy manually this to bin I did not have this error anymore but I get other errors related to another dependecies used by allure ? I have a question Does I need a Project created as .netstandards 2.0 ? or it is OK to use .net 4.6.2

Comment: I send you a PR on GitHub. I reinstalled the package with VS2017 and got no errors. No errors about the missing plugin anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andreas. It really is working and generating the reports I will review the changes that you did and use it. Thanks so much

Comment: Andreas do you know How I can add an attachment ? 
I tried using the guide that was in the repository 
```
using SpecFlow.Allure;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
...
ScenarioContext scenarioContext;
scenarioContext.AddAllureAttachment(path, "Attachment Title");
```
But First I can locate the Specflow.Allure and for this reason I can use the AddAllureAttachment method

Comment: Sorry, never used Allure. I would post a separate question on Stack Overflow or contact the maintainer